# css display none property doesn't work for contenteditable div on internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, contenteditable

I have to insert some span to save / restore selection into a contentEditable div.
Unfortunetely these span have to include at least one character to allow "range.setStart(startNode,0);" function to work properly.
So, this is my group of elements:

```
<div contentEditable='true' id='THE_DIV'>
   some text
      <span id='START_SELECTION'>xxx</span>
         selected text
      <span id='END_SELECTION'>yyy</span>
   other text
</div>
```

Now there should be no problems by setting the span display property to none, but while Fire Fox correctly hides the elements Internet Explorer (7) seems to ignore it.

I've noticed this bheaviour is related to the contentEditable property, but unfortunately I need both (contentEditable parent div and hidden span children).

Have you any suggest?

Thank you in advance,

Flavio.

Comment: Anyway if an inner span is not visible setting the caret / cursor inside it have a very bad effect or doesn't produce any effect.
Therefore I suppose to have to test a different solution for save / restore cursor and selection position while inner HTML of a contentEditable div changes.

Answer (score 2):

This is deliberate behaviour in IE. There is a [little-known command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770023%28VS.85%29.aspx) you can run to disable it:

```
document.execCommand("RespectVisibilityInDesign", false, true);
```

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DGWZF/1/

Also, have you seen [Rangy's selection save and restore module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SelectionSaveRestoreModule)? It does exactly what you're trying to do. Disclosure: I am Rangy's main developer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Tim, 
I have already tried your Rangy plugin (looking at several previous answers) and it is very close to what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I have noticed a strange behaviour in FF while moving the cursor through arrow keys.
Left arrow doesn't work when the cursor comes into a span colse to another span.

I try to be more clear:

```
<div contenteditable='true' id='THE_EDITOR'>
   some text <span class='in_red'>other in red</span><span class='in_blue'>||or in blue</span>
</div>
```

I've used "||" to represent the cursor.
In this case: `<span></span><span>||</span>`
Left arrow fails to move the cursor in FF (I don't understand the reason) but works correctly if there is at least one character between the two elements: `<span></span>[space]<span>||</span>`

If you want to try to reproduce this "bug" the code is (using JQuery):

```
$("#THE_EDITOR").attr("contentEditable","true").keyup(function(){

   var savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();

   //this blok is only to clean the HTML code every time
   $(this).children(".star").each(function(){
      $(this).after($(this).html());
      $(this).remove();
   });

   //to wrap the spewial word "*" with a personal formatting span
   var str = $(this).html();
       str = str.split("*").join("<span class='star'>*</span>");

   $(this).html(str);

   rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel);
   rangy.removeMarkers(savedSel);
});
```

If you try to type two or more "*" in sequence an then move back using left arrow the cursor will not move.
Put a space or another character between them and it will move again.

Comment: If you check event.keyCode and don't change the HTML code when arrow keys are released it will work in FF too.

Thank you for your support.
Flavio.